# Сортировка таблиц Sql с использованием нескольких полей

Tags: sql

Имеется таблица пользователей. Name, Surname, Second_name и другие данные. Причём Имени / фамилия / отчества может вообще не быть.

Таблица выглядит примерно так:
[image: Не сортированная таблица]
Нужно отсортировать данные следующим образом. Сначала строки сравниваются по именам, если у какой-то строки нет имени, за имя в этой сроке берётся фамилия. То есть при сравнении строк сравниваются значения не фамилий, а сравнивается имя в одной строке с фамилией в другой строке.

В итоге отсортированная таблица должна выглядеть вот так:
[image: Отсортированная таблица]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу так сделать? Может есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: order by coalesce(Name, Second_name)

Comment: Интересно, сколько ответов можно получить, если в строку поиска вбить заголовок вопроса

Comment: Желательно без coalesce

Comment: Не нравится COALESCE (чем, кстати?) - сделай то же самое, используя CASE.

Comment: @Akina В sql2 у COALESCE только два параметра, а хотелось бы что-то гибкое, вот CASE возможно то что нужно, спасибо за наводку

Comment: Гм... а Вы не пробовали снабжать свой вопрос ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ тегом? Отлично помогает от лишних вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, так

```
ORDER BY 
 ISNULL(table.name, '') + ISNULL(table.middleName, '') + ISNULL(table.surname, '') asc
```